# Use async methods if available

Tags: c#, file-io, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to switch between System.IO and the StorageFile methods depending on if the user is running Windows 8 or not, without having to create two separate projects? I know I can use System.IO in Windows 8, but I'd like to take advantage of the built in async methods if it's possible (i.e. user is on Win8).

I don't have a Windows 7 machine to test on at the moment, but I'm concerned that missing library errors may be thrown on the program's startup. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please rewrite your question and add some line breaks.

Comment: Maybe look at https://github.com/UbiqRT/Storage not sure how far along it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sl-SI/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) class is not a part of .NET 4.5, it's a part of Windows Runtime. Such classes can easily be recognized by their root namespace `Windows`. Windows Runtime API is available only on Windows 8 and is primarily designed for use in `Windows Store apps`. Although I haven't tried it myself they [can be used in desktop applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx) as well. Still I'm not sure how good that works for file IO classes since Windows store apps run in a sandboxed environment and have only limited access to file system based on the capabilities declared in their manifest.

For file IO in a desktop application I'd stick with .NET classes in `System.IO` namespace. In .NET 4.5 there are several async methods available as well, mostly in [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx), [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) classes and can be used for reading from and writing to files with the async/await paradigm. They are not bound to Windows 8 only, but they do require .NET 4.5 to be installed which [excludes Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx).

Unfortunately there's no async method equivalent to `StorageFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync` in .NET 4.5 that I know of. If you really need to make these calls async as well, you can always wrap the synchronous calls into your own async method which you can call from the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

The async StorageFile methods are part of the .net 4.5 Framework.  You app should deploy the framework as a dependency on install - see [.NET Framework Deployment Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx)

Comment: async/await is part of .NET 4.5, but [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227171.aspx) is not, it's Win RT. You can still implement an async pattern with System.IO.

Comment: also - use System.Environment.OSVersion to get the OS Version - and you can use Hyper-V to run a virtual Windows 7 - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx

Comment: @JimO'Neil In particular, I wanted to use methods like StorageFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync but I guess this won't be possible on non-Win8 devices then?